# Measures and Borel Sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $B(X)$ the Borel Sigma algebra.
In addition, we have $m$ as a measure on the measurable space $(X, B(X))$.

If $Z = \{w$ open : $m(w)=0\}$. Why is Z NOT empty (ok, because the measure is 0, right?) and why does Z admit a maximal element (with respect to set inclusion of course)?

Comment: Not true in general. If the metric space is separable then there is a maximal open set of measure $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment and observation. I edited my question a bit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be the union of all open sets of measure $0$. (The empty set is open and has measure $0$ so the collection $Z$ is not empty). Since $X$ is separable we can write $U$ as a countable union of sets of measure $0$ and hence $U$ itself has measure $0$. It is obviously the largest open set of measure $0$. [ Any seprable metric space is second countable; any union of open sets can be expressed as the union of a countable subfamily].

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But isn't there a concrete maximal element, let's call it M ? Because in my notes, I read that the complement of M is called the "support of the measure". Or is "my" M your U ? :)

Comment: The complement of my $U$ is the support.